# jQuery Click Function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, salesforce

My page was

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery)}"/>

<script type="text/javascript" >
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#contactandaccount').click(function (){
        alert("hellooo");// it is never entering here
        jQuery("contactandaccount").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<div id="sidebar">
                <ul style="display: block;" class="leftnav">
                    <li class="submneu2"><a href="#contactandaccount"  data-toggle="tab" ><i class="icon icon-tasks"></i> <span>Contacts and Accounts</span> </a></li></ul>
 <div id="contactandaccount" style="display: none;"  >
                     <apex:include pageName="Includepage"/>
                 </div>    
            </div>
 </apex:page>
```

When I click on Contact and Account link nothing is happening.Any ideas on this please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are clicking on a div not on anchor tag//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the link and the div.

```
jQuery('#contactandaccount')
```

isn't a selector for the link but for the div with id `contactandaccount`.

You should

1) give an id to your link :

```
<a id=somelink href="#contactandaccount"  data-toggle="tab" >
```

2) use this id in the selector :

```
jQuery('#somelink').click(function (){
```